# Is F one-to-one in some open neighbourhood of $(0,0,0)$ in $\Bbb R^3$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, vector-spaces

Here $F:\Bbb R^3\rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ is given by $F(x,y,z)=(e^{x}\cos(y),e^{x}\sin(y),z^3)$.

The question is: Is $F$ one-to-one in some open neighbourhood of $(0,0,0)$ in $\Bbb R^3$?

I have spent sometime on this question. I deduced $dF$ is invertible everywhere in $\Bbb R^3$ for $z\ne 0$ (is that correct?) But so far I have not found if it has something to do with the question.

Could someone please help? Any help would be appreciate. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x,y,z),(a,b,c) \in \mathbb R^3$ such that $|y-b|<1$ and $F(x,y,z)=F(a,b,c)$

Then we get $(e^{x}\cos(y),e^{x}\sin(y))  = ( e^{a}\cos(b),e^{a}\sin(b) )$ and $z^3=c^3$.

It follows: $x=a,z=c$ and $y-b=2k \pi$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$

From $|y-b|<1$ we derive $k=0$, hence $y=b$.

Consequence: if $(x,y,z),(a,b,c) \in B_1(0,0,0)$ and $F(x,y,z)=F(a,b,c)$, then $(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)$

Comment: May I please ask how can I deduce $x=a$ and $y-b=2k\pi$ from $e^x(cos(y))=e^a(cos(b))$ and $e^x(sin(y))=e^a(sin(b))$? I tried translating them into the tangent function by taking the ratio, but it gives $y=b+k\pi$.

Comment: You can write $(e^{x}\cos(y),e^{x}\sin(y))  = ( e^{a}\cos(b),e^{a}\sin(b) )$ in the comple form as: $e^{x+iy}=e^{a+ib}$. Then there is $k \in \mathbb Z$ with $x+iy=a+ib +2 k \pi i$

Comment: Got it! Thanks for patience!

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if wrong:

The point $(x, y, z )$ is mapped onto the same point as $(x, y+2π, z)$.

Restrict your ball around $(0,0,0)$ to $r <  2π$.

So the given function is one to one in $B_r (0,0,0)$